# Basic hamburger-menu HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, hamburger-menu

my goal is to make simple hamburger-menu with JS.
I'm beginner and this is my 1st Javascript project.
At first my code after clicking showed the menu, but after I tried to code, that it should unshow after clicking again, it doesnt work at all, and I dont get any error message.
My code is below:

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('navId');
var hamburgerIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-bars')[0];
var showMenuIs = false;

function showMenu() {
  if (showMenuIs == false) {
    hamburgerIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
      menu.classList.add("showMenu");
      let showMenu = true;
    })
  } else {
    hamburgerIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
      menu.classList.add("navId");
      let showMenu = false;

    })
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 50%;
  display: absolute;
  font-size: 5.7vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#main-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.navId {
  background-color: black;
  height: 7.2vh;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.showMenu {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 7.2vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 1s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/884fc3b032.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">



    <div id="main-header">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>

    </div>
    <div id="main-menu">
      <nav class="navId">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"><a href=""></a></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"><a href=""></a></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"><a href=""></a></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"><a href=""></a></i>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please, can you double check your code? I can't see any hamburger menu?

Comment: not sure, what do u mean exactly now, but the menu is icon from FontAwesome           
 " <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>" this

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qI6rVak5vKFA This is what we see when we run your code snippet.

Comment: @Blocaj your code is faulty because every time you call showMenu you add other listeners that will compromise the functionality.... you also don't use the right method to check if it's open or not... check my solution.

Comment: oh, i think its because i'm using "vh" for the icon, ill fix it as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get menu by id but you specified a class for it....

use this...

```
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('navId')[0]; //< HERE

function toggleMenu(){
     if(showMenuIs){
         menu.classList.add("navId"); //< this is useless?
         menu.classList.remove("showMenu");
         showMenuIs = false;
      } else {
         menu.classList.remove("navId"); //< this is useless?
         menu.classList.add("showMenu");
         showMenuIs = true;
      }
}


hamburgerIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
     toggleMenu();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, when I tried using this solution I recieved this error: js.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at toggleMenu (js.js:10:14)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (js.js:18:5)

Comment: @Blocaj i edited the answer with the correction of the bug (your bug :P)

Comment: btw `menu.classList.add("navId")` and  `menu.classList.remove("navId");` are useless in my opinion... you can have more classes...